# Check if user is already logged in via Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, ldap, windows-authentication

I'm using LDAP Authentication in MVC Application.

My Login methods (both GET and POST) looks like as bellow:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    //Check if User is Logged in Via Windows Authentication.
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         // Check with AD
         if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
         {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, true);
            // Create a Profile Information Session on Server.
            // Other logic goes here.....
         }
      }

      // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
      ModelState.AddModelError("", @"The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
      return View(model);
   }
}
```

Here, How to check if USER is already logged in via Windows Credentials? Say, If I logged in to my machine and when I access this application then I should directly land on Home page instead of Login page. How to achieve this?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why would the land on the Login page? Have you set that as the default start page?

Comment: Yes, in Web.Config file:   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" name=".ADAuthCookie" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>

Comment: Why? The default should be your home page. And it appears your wanting to mix Windows and Forms authentication - not an easy task (and BTW, the code in your comment is not setting the default page)

Comment: How to make it LDAP specific? I just wanted to store some session after login.

Comment: The link in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437939/is-there-a-good-approach-to-combine-windows-authentication-and-forms-authenticat/7438340#7438340) might help